# how to read xml data and convert it into array

Tags: php, curl, xml-parsing

How to read xml data in which no `<? xml ?>` tag is mentaioned and convert it into array,
XML data comes from url, see my below XML data:

```
<Item>
  <itemID>140</itemID>
  <systemSku readonly="true">210000000140</systemSku>
  <defaultCost currency="USD">6.5</defaultCost>
  <avgCost currency="USD">6.5</avgCost>
  <tax>true</tax>
  <archived>false</archived>
  <itemType>default</itemType>
  <description>Adult Baltic Amber - 17 inch - Raw Round Lemon Necklace</description>
  <modelYear>0</modelYear>
  <upc></upc>
  <ean></ean>
  <customSku>BANK-RL-17R</customSku>
  <manufacturerSku></manufacturerSku>
  <timeStamp>2013-11-09T09:32:42+00:00</timeStamp>
  <categoryID>8</categoryID>
  <taxClassID>0</taxClassID>
  <departmentID>0</departmentID>
  <itemMatrixID>0</itemMatrixID>
  <manufacturerID>4</manufacturerID>
  <seasonID>0</seasonID>
  <defaultVendorID>0</defaultVendorID>
  <Prices>
    <ItemPrice>
      <amount currency="USD">32.95</amount>
      <useType readonly="true">Default</useType>
    </ItemPrice>
    <ItemPrice>
      <amount currency="USD">0</amount>
      <useType readonly="true">MSRP</useType>
    </ItemPrice>
  </Prices>
</Item>
```

I have used below code php for reading data:

```
   <?php            
//header('content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$url = "http://east6.merchantos.com/API/Account/59675/Item";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$output = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);
$total_product_item = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" ?>' .$output);
$total_product_item = object_to_array($total_product_item);
$total_product_item = $total_product_item['Item'];
//$count_products_qty = count($total_product_item); 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($total_product_item); echo "</pre>";


    function object_to_array($data) 
        {
                if ((! is_array($data)) and (! is_object($data))) return 'xxx'; //$data;

                $result = array();

                $data = (array) $data;
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    if (is_object($value)) $value = (array) $value;
                    if (is_array($value)) 
                    $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
                    else
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                }

                return  $result;
        }

?>
```

Please help me out.
Thanks !

Comment: Google PHP XML Parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correct the missing `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` is the problem. Add it before your output and then parse it:

```
$total_product_item = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" ?>' . $output);
```

Comment: I have added this but still it gives below error and returning 'x'.             
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\lightspeed\get_product_items.php on line 13

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml version="1.0" ?> in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\lightspeed\get_product_items.php on line 13

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\lightspeed\get_product_items.php on line 13

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Item' in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\lightspeed\get_product_items.php on line 15

x

Comment: It works for me with your test XML input. Show me your updated code.